# How do I calculate the time complexity of the function?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```
int coin_row(int[] array, int index, int length)
{
    if (index >= length) //beyond last coin
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int value = array[index];
    if (index >= length - 1) //last coin
    {
        return value;
    }
    else if (index >= length - 2) //second last coin
    {
        return max(value, coin+row(array, index+1);
    }

    return max(value+coin_row(array, index+2,length), coin_row(array, index+1,length));
}
```

What should I do when calculating the time complexity of this recursive function?

Comment: Short answer: Benchmark it for various values of *N*.

Comment: If you're using C++ you should *really, really* be using `std::vector` instead of C-style array/size pairs.

Comment: Is `coin+row` a typo? You're also recursively calling this function with 2 arguments, but it has 3.

Comment: Since the code can't be compiled the complexity is either O(1) or O(0).

Comment: Instead of `if (index >= length - 1)` consider using `if (index > length)` as it's got a little less brain overhead. Compiler probably will make the change for you, but code is for humans. Make it easy on them.

Comment: @user4581301 When I change it this way, I get an index of the range error.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't pay enough attention to the direction of the operator.

Comment: Is `coin+row` a typo? Did you mean `coin_row`

Comment: @Tas i mean coin_row

Comment: @Tas can you comment on time complexity? my friend

Comment: Nah lol only here for typos

Comment: What programming language is this? Is this Java? What is `int[] array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's O(n).

To see this: write a recurrence relation. Here is it `T(n) = T(n+1) + O(1)` and `T(l) = 1`. The O(1) in the first equation comes from the max() function.

Since each step requires `O(1)` operations, and there are n recusive calls where n is the length. The time complexity is O(n*1) = O(n).